# Is it possible to create AC with just battery, transistor and coils?

Tags: batteries

I set a circuit that shows how the electromagnetic induction works. But as what i studied in  physics class, there will be alternating current but there's nothing that seems to create an AC! All electric components that i used was coil, breadboard, transistor, resistance, battery and LED. The picture and circuit map is like this
[image]

[image]

Comment: Something like this? https://paksc.org/pk/science-experiments-urdu/make-your-own-simple-tesla-coil-video-urdu/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very possible.  In fact, the original Touch-Tone keypad used a 1-transistor circuit to generate two different sine waves *at the same time*, one of the most brilliant analog circuits ever.  But I digress...

Without an actual schematic, I can't say why your circuit does not work.  But based on the picture there are not enough parts.  Specifically, there needs to be at least one capacitor to create a resonant L-C tank, and resistors to bias the transistor into the middle of its linear active region.  Search the innergoogle for 'L-C oscillator circuit' to get many schematics.

What is the battery polarity?
What is the transistor part number?
What is the transistor type?
What is the orientation of the yellow and blue coils?

Comment: You can arrange the coils such that self-capacity or capacitance between two coils provides the resonance. The orientation of the feedback coil is important to provide positive feedback to the transistor.

Comment: Red lines for (+) and black lines for (-). It doesn't mention any transistor part number or type. Orientation of coils? What does that mean exactly? Ingredients?

Answer (score 0):

Of course that is possible, and the circuit that implements this function is a (one-transistor) oscilator.

But I very much doubt that the circuit you are using, which seems to be this one:

[image]

is oscillating. But I could be wrong. Does the LED on your green coil light up continuously?

Comment: Yep, it actually worked well with continuous illuminating. But like on the above diagram(one transistor oscilator), is it powerful enough for my circuit's first-coil to create high voltage so that the second-coil can receive its induced EMF?

Answer (score -1):

Pulsed DC can be seen as AC plus a static DC component.

[image: Pulsed DC]

Transformers cannot transfer DC, that's why there is only AC flowing on the secondary.

Comment: You mean transistor serves as making DC pulsed(act as a switch), so it is possbile for the secondary coild to be induced and turn on the LED?

Comment: In your setup, the blue coil is the primary, the yellow coil is the secondary. Your green coil is an additional, loosely coupled secondary which does not influence the circuit too much (only by being a load).